# Obtain real Class object for Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using Spring to inject beans. And I am using some annotations to annotate bean methods (Security, TransactionManagement, ExceptionHanling, Logging). The problem is:

I want to create JUnit test to check if I forgot annotate some methods. But Spring returns $ProxyXXX class without any annotations on methods..

```
Method[] methods = logic.getClass().getMethods();

  for (Method method : methods) {
     Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();   // empty array!
```

How can I get annotations for method or obtain a real class object?

P.S. Spring 2.5.6, JDKDynamicProxy (not CGLib)

Comment: Analogous question for Seam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979717/losing-class-custom-annotation-for-proxy-classes

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Spring's interface-based proxies implement [`TargetClassAware`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/TargetClassAware.html).

Comment: Nice! Sorry for outdated comment, I used `AopUtils.getTargetClass(Object)` from "see also" section in the provided link.

Answer (score 25):

Or you can just call: [AopUtils.getTargetClass(java.lang.Object)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils.html#getTargetClass-java.lang.Object-) It is a `static` method call.

Answer (score 23):

You can cast the proxied object to get the object and class it acts as a proxy for (see [TargetSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/TargetSource.html)):

```
Advised advised = (Advised) proxy;
Class<?> cls = advised.getTargetSource().getTargetClass();
```

Generally you should follow the Spring principles and keep obtaining the correct class as unobtrusive as possible. Meaning that as little classes as possible should depend on the Spring Framework APIs (maybe add a ClassLocator and a SpringProxyClassLocator implementation).

Answer (score 9):

`AopUtils.getTargetClass` only unwraps one level. Use `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(instance)` instead.

(I'm aware this is an 11 years old question, but it's still coming up high in Google, so it benefits from a new answer)